# Docker and Github Integration - Where did the Github Files go?

Tags: git, github, docker

I'm trying out docker and github integration.

What I've done currently is that I placed a Dockerfile in my repository: https://github.com/mxlei01/YouTube-Channel-Search.

Ignoring the git clone command for now, I've tried:

```
docker pull mxlei01/youtube-channel-search
docker images (to find all the images)
docker run mxlei01/youtube-channel-search
```

However, when I tried to extract the file by using export:

```
docker ps -a
docker export <container ID> > file.tar
tar -xvf file.tar
```

I was not able to find any of my files inside my git repo by using the command:

```
find . -name "mongo.py"
```

So I've added a command to fetch the project manually, however, I don't think this is the proper way, however, it might be do-able.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

---------EDIT----------

Turns out you can just do a copy like this:

```
RUN mkdir /application
COPY Tornado-Application /application/Tornado-Application
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the vote down? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:wheezy

#Create a folder, and git pull the repo
RUN mkdir /application
```

It will create the folder /application, but it won't copy anything in it.
At least, some COPY directives would be needed to include in the image the other folders of your GitHub project.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply!  I know that it will only create a folder called application. But do you know where do copy from that will include the files in the GitHub project? The Documentation is here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/github/, but it doesn't say how to move files in from GitHub. I thought they do it automatic, but it turns out they don't. That's why I tried to export, and use find to find my files.

Comment: @user1157751 " it doesn't say how to move files in from GitHub" why not add to your Dockerfile some COPY directives in order to copy the folders of your repo in the built image?